# How to use ComponentWillReceieveProp in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to convert a class component into a functional component with hooks, but i am having a challenge on how to use an equivalent lifecycle of  ComponentWillReceiveProps.

Log in form : Class Component:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     emial:"",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event){
        window.history.pushState(null, document.title,  window.location.href);
    });
}
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {// want to replace with hook equivalent
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/recruitcentral"); // push user to dashboard when they login
    }
if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
const userData = {
      email: this.props.username,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData); 
  };
render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;


    return (
            <>
     
      <Row>
       

      
      <Col>
      
                 <div>
           
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div className={styles.formWrapper}>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
                        <div className="email">
              <label htmlFor="email"></label>
              <input
                 onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email || errors.emailnotfound
                  })}
              />
              <div className="Input__line" />
                <label htmlFor="email" >Enter your email</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.email}
                  {errors.emailnotfound}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  error={errors.password}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password || errors.passwordincorrect
                  })}
                />
                <div className="Input__line" />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.password}
                  {errors.passwordincorrect}
                </span>
              </div>
            <div className={styles.createAccount}>
              <button type="submit">Log in</button>
           
            </div>

             <div className={styles.createAccount}>
              <button  onClick={()=> this.props.history.push("/register")}type="submit">Create Account</button>
          
            </div>
         
            </form>
</div>
</div>
</Col>

      </Row>
    
            </>
```

Login Form :Functional Component

```
function Login(props) {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    email:'',
    password: '',
    errors: {}
});

const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const { username, password } = inputs;
    const auth =useSelector(state=>state.auth)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const location = useLocation();


    // reset login status
    useEffect(() => {    
      dispatch(logoutUser()); 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
   // code to perform same function as componentWillReceiveProps here
    }
}, [])
```

I know useEffect() will be used, but i really dont know how to implement it

Comment: `componentWillRecieveProps` is for all practical purposes deprecated with the recommendation being to use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency is the functional component equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you give me an idea on how to structure the code in a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillRecieveProps` is for all practical purposes deprecated with the recommendation being to use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency is the functional component equivalent.

For the first side-effect, navigating to "/recruitcentral" when user is authenticated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    props.history.push("/recruitcentral");
  }
}, [auth]); // <-- Note: may complain about missing dependency like `history`, you can add these
```